# Reducing computation time of counting word frequency in a corpus (python)

Tags: python, nlp

```
def foo(self, n):
    wordFreqDict = defaultdict(int)
    resultList = []

    for sentence in self.allSentences:
        for word in self.wordSet:
            if word in sentence:
                wordFreqDict[word] += 1

    for candidateWord in wordFreqDict:
        if wordFreqDict[candidateWord] >= n:
            resultList.append(candidateWord)

    return resultList
```

My function basically return the list of words where a word is in the list iff it occurs in at least n sentences. What I am trying to do is just iterate through the self.allSentences is a list of list of words(sentence) and iterate through the self.wordSet(all unique words in the corpus) and add the frequency of each word to the dictionary (wordFreqDict).

Then loop through the wordFreqDict and add a word with frequency >= n into the resultList.

I am assuming that this will work, but it's taking too long time to check the result.

Is there a way to make it for efficient and make the computation time shorter?

EDIT:

Here is how the self.allSentences is computed

```
def storeAllSentences(self, corpus):
    for sentence in corpus:
        self.allSentences.append(sentence)
```

and the self.wordSet:

```
def getUniqueWordSet(self, corpus):
    for sentence in self.allSentences:
        for word in sentence:
            self.wordSet.append(word)

    self.wordSet = set(self.wordSet)
```

Comment: how about using threads?

Comment: `set` + `Counter` should really boost this.

Comment: @Stack, no. If the algorithm doesn't work well in a single processing environment, it makes no sense to parallelise it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @user6792790 Before doing that, I need a little bit of information. What is the input to your function? Where are the documents, and how do you tokenise sentences?

Comment: Maybe an aside, but it looks like you're currently counting the number of sentences that contain each word as opposed to word frequency.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Just edited. The input n is the threshold for frequency and the corpus is called by doing corpus = readFileToCorpus('text.txt')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assumption here is that a word is chosen if it uniquely appears in *at least* `n` sentences. So, even if it occurs 10 times in a single sentence, that's still once.

A couple of glaring issues are your nested loops and your `in` check on a string. This is effectively cubic in complexity. It should be possible to reduce this drastically using a `set` + `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def foo(self, n):
    c = Counter()
    for sent in self.allSentences:
        c.update(set(sent))

    resultSet = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[1] >= n, c.most_common()))

    return resultSet
```

Here, I use regex to remove special characters and punctuation, following which I split and retrieve all unique words in the sentence. The `Counter` is then updated.

Finally, extract all words of the desired frequency (or more) using `itertools.takewhile` and return.

---

If `sent` is a string sentence, you might use `re` based filtering to remove punctuation and then split:

```
import re

tempWordSet = set(re.sub('[^\w\s]+', '', sent).split())  
c.update(tempWordSet)
```

This does not take into consideration whether a word belongs to `self.wordSet` or not. So if you want that as well, you might modify the first loop a bit to include a `filter` step:

```
 c.update(set(filter(lambda x: x in self.wordSet, sent)))
```

Or, using the second technique:

```
 tempWordSet = set(filter(lambda x: x in self.wordSet, 
                         re.sub('[^\w\s]+', '', sent).split()))
```

---

On an unrelated note, are you trying to perform text mining? You might be interested in looking into [TFIDF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me a "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" on the line: tempWordSet = set(re.sub('[^\w\s]+', '', sent).split())

Comment: @user6792790 Oh, `sent` isn't a string? Is it a list of words?

Comment: Yeah. snet is a list of words. Sorry I should have clarified

Comment: @user6792790 No problem, I have edited my answer. Should work now. Also see the option with `filter` and use it if it is needed.

Comment: @user6792790 No problem! How's the performance now? I'd wager it should be much better now.

Comment: Yeah it became so much faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The set *wordSet* is probably at least two orders of magnitude larger than the words in a single sentence. Therefore it makes sense loop by words in a sentence. However, this requires that splitting a sentence is not a really slow operation. If it is, you should do the whole process in getUniqueWordSet. Here's only the first for-loop changed:

```
def foo(self, n):
wordFreqDict = defaultdict(int)
resultList = []

for sentence in self.allSentences:
   for word in sentence: 
      # This if may be left out if allSentences is guaranteed to stay the same after storing them
      if word in self.wordSet:  
          wordFreqDict[word] += 1

for candidateWord in wordFreqDict:
    if wordFreqDict[candidateWord] >= n:
        resultList.append(candidateWord)

return resultList
```